# Python dictionary values check not empty and not None

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary which may or may not have one or both keys 'foo' and 'bar'. Depending on whether both or either are available, I need to do different things. Here is what I am doing (and it works):

```
foo = None
bar = None

if 'foo' in data:
    if data['foo']:
        foo = data['foo']

if 'bar' in data:
    if data['bar']:
        bar = data['bar']

if foo is not None and bar is not None:
    dofoobar()
elif foo is not None:
    dofoo()
elif bar is not None:
    dobar()
```

This seems too verbose - what is the idiomatic way to do this in Python (2.7.10)?

Comment: you can do `foo = data.get('foo')`

Comment: @EricDuminil No, `dofoobar()` is different from `dofoo()` followed by `dobar()`

Comment: Wait, is it a typo with `bar` and `email` or do you really check two different keys?

Comment: @EricDuminil Was a typo. Fixed now. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another way to refactor your code :

```
foo = data.get('foo')
bar = data.get('bar')

if foo:
    if bar:
        dofoobar()
    else:
        dofoo()
elif bar:
    dobar()
```

I'm not sure it's cleaner or more readable than ChristianDean's answer, though.

Just for fun, you could also use a `dict` with boolean tuples as keys and functions as values:

```
{(True, True):dofoobar, (False, True):dobar, (True, False):dofoo}
```

You'd use it this way:

```
data = {'foo': 'something'}

foo = data.get('foo')
bar = data.get('bar')

def dofoobar():
    print('foobar!')

def dobar():
    print('bar!')

def dofoo():
    print('foo!')

actions = {(True, True):dofoobar, (False, True):dobar, (True, False):dofoo}
action = actions.get((foo is not None, bar is not None))
if action:
    action()
#foo!
```

Comment: I like the first approach better than other answers (though the second one is more fun :-)) - actually, (in @ChristianDean's answer) I think checking for `not None` after `data.get()` does not validate that the strings are non-empty.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to shorten your code. Rather than raising a `KeyError` when a key is not present, `None` is returned:

```
foo = data.get('foo')
bar = data.get('email')

if foo is not None and bar is not None:
    dofoobar()
elif foo is not None:
    dofoo()
elif bar is not None:
    dobar()
```

Comment: An idiomatic alternative for the first `if` clause could be `all([foo, bar])` *if all that matters is truthyness, not exact comparison with `None`*

Comment: @LukasGraf Well, I'm not exactly sure about that :| Wouldn't just doing `if foo and bar` be faster and cleaner if all that matters is truthyness?

Comment: @LukasGraf I'm not sure this was the intention, but in the OP's code all that matters is truthiness, because if `data['foo']` doesn't evaluate to true, `foo` will never get a value other than `None`.

Comment: @ChristianDean that's true, that should be functionally equivalent and even cleaner. I don't think it would be significantly fast, as `all()` also short-circuits (returns on the first non-True element).

Comment: @yinnonsanders yeah, I noticed that as well. However, Christian's answer does demonstrate nicely that *if* you want to make that distinction, you compare the values to `None` (and do so using `is` instead of `==`), which is why I like it.

Comment: Thanks, Christian. can't we remove the `not None` part in all `if` and `elif` checks? Since I want to call dofoobar() only when foo and bar are neither None nor empty strings, can't I just say `if foo and bar` or `if all([foo, bar])` instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> data = {'foo': 1}
>>> foo = data.get('foo')
>>> foo
1
>>> bar = data.get('bar')
>>> bar
>>> bar is None
True
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foo = None
bar = None

try:
  foo=data["foo"]
except:
  pass

try:
  bar=data["bar"]
except:
  pass



if foo and bar:
    dofoobar()
elif foo:
    dofoo()
elif bar:
    dobar()
```

You can use try/except.Also get attribute is also perfect

Comment: You are right. EAFP is the commonly preferred idiom in Python. However, `dict.get` already implements the logic for you, so using it here just makes the code more verbose.

Comment: ya I thought providing an alternative would also be fine